# js isn't executing on first page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, divi

I'm working with a WordPress site using the Divi theme. I have inserted a JavaScript code into the body via the theme options. However, I'm encountering an issue where the script doesn't executes until the second page load. Additionally, it doesn't seem to run at all when using Incognito mode. This script is intended to create interactive tooltips that respond to user actions, enhancing the user experience on the site.

```
window.onload = function() {
    function getTooltipContent(id) {
        let content = '';

        switch (id) {
            case 'Kreis1':
                // some text
                break;
            // Other cases
            default:
                content = ''; 
        }

        return content; 
    }

    const kreise = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-container g[id^="Kreis"]');
    const infoContainer = document.getElementById('info-container');
    const infoText = document.getElementById('info-text');
    const svgContainer = document.querySelector('.svg-container');

    kreise.forEach(kreis => {
        kreis.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const content = getTooltipContent(kreis.id);
            infoText.innerHTML = content; // Tooltip content is set here

            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                infoContainer.classList.add('info-container-mobile-active');
            } else {
                infoContainer.classList.add('active');
                svgContainer.classList.add('active');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I've tried using both the DOMContentLoaded event and the jQuery ready function to address this issue, but these approaches did not resolve the problem.

Comment: perhaps there's dynamic content you think is there on page load, but actually isn't there yet - what errors do you see in the browser *developer* console? if none, add `console.log(kreise.length)` in your code, and see what it outputs in the browser *developer* tools console

Comment: Perhaps there is another onload - they will overwrite each other. Instead use the safer `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() { .....});` remember to add the last bracket

Comment: I also strongly suggest you delegate the click to the nearest static container instead of adding it to each `kreis`

Comment: @mplungjan the jqueery ready function would've fixed that :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, I missed that statement. Perhaps it was not implemented correctly. For example I see MANY asking such questions who are loading jQuery twice, in different versions too

Comment: also, @mplungjan, it's `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` isn't it? edit: nevermind, seems both work and `window` runs after `document`

Comment: I use window.addEventListner for DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it. Just to let you know, I managed to fix the issue by putting the script into a code module in Divi Builder, right under the SVG. Now everything's working great.